# Returning complex query on update SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return query with multiple joins and with clause after updating something.

For example my query is:

```
WITH orders AS (
  SELECT product_id, SUM(amount) AS orders
  FROM orders_summary
  GROUP BY product_id
)
SELECT p.id, p.name,
p.date_of_creation,
o.orders, s.id AS store_id,
s.name AS store_name
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN orders AS o
ON p.id = o.product_id
LEFT JOIN stores AS s
ON s.id = p.store_id
WHERE p.id = '1'
```

| id | name | date | orders | store_id | store_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pen | 11/16/2022 | 10 | 1 | jj |
| 2 | pencil | 11/10/2022 | 30 | 2 | ff |

I want to return the exact query but with updated result in my update:

```
UPDATE products
SET name = 'ABC'
WHERE id = '1'
RETURNING up_query
```

Desired result on update:

| id | name | date | orders | store_id | store_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 11/16/2022 | 10 | 1 | jj |

Comment: @JonasMetzler im sorry for confusing question. I want to return the first query on returning in update sql. I don't want to call 2 separate queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `UPDATE products ... RETURNING *`. That may get you the content of the row you just updated.

As for `UPDATE .... RETURNING someQuery`, You Can't Do That™. You want to do both the update and a SELECT operation in one go. But that's not possible.

If you must be sure your SELECT works on the precisely the same data as you just UPDATEd, you can wrap your two queries in a `BEGIN;` / `COMMIT;` transaction. That prevents concurrent users from making changes between your UPDATE and SELECT.

Comment: Thank you that was my exact question `You want to do both the update and a SELECT operation in one go. But that's not possible.`

Comment: You're welcome. SQL takes some getting used to, eh?